# Move a single column forward by a few dates in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to move all values in the column `val` by 3 days ahead in the following dataframe:

```
datetime    val val_b
12/20/2010      23
12/21/2010      12
12/22/2010  23  27
12/23/2010      26
12/24/2010      28
12/25/2010      17
12/26/2010      26
12/27/2010  21  14
12/28/2010      20
12/29/2010      18
12/30/2010  15  22
12/31/2010      20
1/1/2011        13
1/2/2011    12  30
1/3/2011        25
1/4/2011        15
1/5/2011        19
1/6/2011        14
```

I tried using the `pd.DateOffset` function, but hat moves all the columns ahead and I do not want that.

Comment: df.val = df.val.shift(-3) , can it work for your case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First create `DatetimeIndex` and then use [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html) with parameter `freq`:

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
df = df.set_index('datetime')

df['val'] = df['val'].shift(3, freq='d')
print (df)
             val  val_b
datetime               
2010-12-20   NaN     23
2010-12-21   NaN     12
2010-12-22   NaN     27
2010-12-23   NaN     26
2010-12-24   NaN     28
2010-12-25  23.0     17
2010-12-26   NaN     26
2010-12-27   NaN     14
2010-12-28   NaN     20
2010-12-29   NaN     18
2010-12-30  21.0     22
2010-12-31   NaN     20
2011-01-01   NaN     13
2011-01-02  15.0     30
2011-01-03   NaN     25
2011-01-04   NaN     15
2011-01-05  12.0     19
2011-01-06   NaN     14
```

Comment: thanks @jezrael, should there be a `.values` at the end of the `df['val'].shift(3, freq='d')`

Comment: @user308827 - So if missing `.values` it not matched correctly?

Comment: I get this error: `*** ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`

Comment: @user308827 - I test it and `.values` not shift data for me. There is realy problem with duplicated datetimes, possible hack solution is `df.index = [df.index, df.groupby('datetime').cumcount()]

df = df.unstack()
df['val'] = df['val'].shift(3, freq='d')
df = df.stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True)`